# What is the correct usage of const member in delegating constructor?

Tags: c++

I want to use `const` class member variable in delegating constructor. Check the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class T
{
  const int c = 100;
public:

  T(int i)
  {
      cout << i << endl;
  }

  T() : T(c)
  {

  }
};

int main()
{
    T t;

    return 0;
}
```

The running result is:

> 0

I assume the output should be `100`. So per my understanding, during delegating constructor, the `T::c` is not initialized. I modify the `c` as a `static const` member:

```
class T
{
  static const int c = 100;
  ......
}
```

This time the result is `100`:

> 100

But after checking [static member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) reference, I can't find the evidence that `static const` member is guaranteed initialized during delegating constructor. What is the correct usage of `const` member in delegating constructor? Is `static const` member guaranteed initialized during delegating constructor?

Comment: Why do you expect `c` be initialized before the constructor is called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a constructor delegates construction work to another constructor, that other constructor is responsible for initializing all members and base classes.

Hence in your first constructor data member `c` has not yet been initialized.

Re

> **”** I can’t find the evidence that static const member is guaranteed initialized during delegating constructor.

… it’s not: it's initialized as part of static initialization, which happens *before* the first statement in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is static const member guaranteed initialized during delegating constructor?**

From [basic.start.static#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2)

> Constant initialization is performed if a variable or temporary
>   object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a
>   **constant initializer** for the entity.

Thus `c` is initialized to `100`

> **What is the correct usage of const member in delegating constructor?**

I think the confusion is not about the delegating constructor but the initialization.

`c` has not yet been initialized in `T(): T(c)`

Comment: "c where no initialization will happen, for it isn't an array nor a class type". An initialiser is specified for `c`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, sorry got all mixed up with `T t` and the delegating constructor. updated.